# PostGIS upgrade 2.2.1 -> 2.5.0 Database Import Errors

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.6, geos, postgis-installation

I'm moving a database from PostGIS 2.2.1 to 2.5.0 (PG 9.6). I pg_dumped the old database and am using pg_restore to import it.

Everything appears to go fine but I'm getting these two errors. Is this something I need to worry about or can just ignore them?

```
pg_restore: creating AGGREGATE "public.accum(geometry)"
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 4925; 1255 348862 AGGREGATE accum(geometry) aed
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  type "pgis_abs" does not exist
Command was: CREATE AGGREGATE accum(geometry) (
    SFUNC = public.pgis_geometry_accum_transfn,
    STYPE = pgis_abs,
    FINALFUNC = pgis_geometry_accum_finalfn
);
```

and..

```
pg_restore: creating AGGREGATE "public.makeline(geometry)"
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 4927; 1255 348864 AGGREGATE makeline(geometry) aed
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  type "pgis_abs" does not exist
Command was: CREATE AGGREGATE makeline(geometry) (
    SFUNC = public.pgis_geometry_accum_transfn,
    STYPE = pgis_abs,
    FINALFUNC = pgis_geometry_makeline_finalfn
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the `pgis_abs` column is a dummy column, [as per this commit](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/commit/6dea41a252232feaad3a2eb8fd45bde551e63242):

> #4035, remove dummy pgis_abs type from aggregate/collect routines

Sounds like you should be able to drop the `pgis_abs` column before performing the upgrade

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](http://enterprisedb.com)

Comment: I'll just add to this for others. Using pg_restore was required as the postgis data was not loading in as valid sql for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you should use "postgis_restore.pl" when restore the pg_dumped file with postgis extension, not pg_restore command itself.

https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/svn-trunk/utils/postgis_restore.pl.in